# reading from PCA 9554 (i2c) in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, i2c

I am trying to read data from a PCA9554 in arduino.
The hard ware setup is simple: all 3 address line of the PCA9554 is connected to high (+5 v), so the address of this device is 0x27.
The code that I am using to read the value is as follow:

```
 uint8_t i2cr8(uint8_t dev, uint8_t addr)
 {
      uint8_t val=-1;
      Wire.requestFrom(dev,(uint8_t)1);
      if(Wire.available()) {
          val = Wire.read();
       }
       return val;
  }
```

but it always read 0.

What is wrong with this code?

I think there is no error with hardware as I can read from other devices on I2C bus.

Comment: `uint8_t val=-1;` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin: My bad, changed it to val=0xff; which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works:

```
//exact address depends on IC model and <A0:A2> wiring
#define dip_addr       0x38 
...

byte rdata = 0xFF;

Wire.beginTransmission(dip_addr);
Wire.send((uint8_t)0);  
Wire.endTransmission();

Wire.requestFrom(dip_addr,1);

if (Wire.available()) rdata = Wire.receive();

Serial.println ("DIP: " + String(rdata, DEC));
```